# Prevent tampering to files in Documents directory on iOS

Tags: ios

A user can take a video that is say up to a maximum 5 seconds long, and then save it to their documents directory, and then upload that video to the server at a later time.

However, it is easy for the user to go in and replace that video file with a much larger video file, say 10 minutes long, just by browsing the documents directory with an app like iExplorer. Is there a way to make the files tamper proof? Perhaps some sort of hash that I can compare files with to make sure they weren't tampered with?

Comment: In reality, you'll find the majority of your users aren't going to bother to go those extremes.

Comment: Yes, you can use some sort of hash.  Of course, you either need to append the hash to the file or store it elsewhere.  And in your scenario it seems like it would be easier to just check the file size.

Comment: You can make md5 hash of the file and remember it within the app: http://iosdevelopertips.com/core-services/create-md5-hash-from-nsstring-nsdata-or-file.html

Comment: I agree with @HotLicks -- just check the file size.

Comment: Why do the files need to be tamper proof in the first place? You are checking the size on server side when it gets uploaded to the server, right? Is that not enough?

Comment: He may not want to waste bandwidth, so it's a valid question. But, I'd just prevent any file over like 2-3 Megabytes from being uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just about file size, check the size before uploading. If you want to make sure it's the same exact file - use something like an md5 hash on it.

http://iosdevelopertips.com/core-services/create-md5-hash-from-nsstring-nsdata-or-file.html

Answer (score 0):

for every file you record and save in the directory, you can save the creation/modification date, so if the file is not in your list or that date doesn't much you are sure that user modify it.

to get date:

```
NSString *videoPath = [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:videoName];
NSDictionary *attributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:videoPath error:&error];
```

NSDate *Date = [attributes objectForKey:NSFileModificationDate]; //or NSFileCreationDate